# How can I separate cores in different group and used by multiple function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, batch-processing, parfor

I am currently writing a matlab program. There's a function, denote it as `myfunc(..)`. `myfunc` has a `parfor` which requires 4 CPUs. I need to run `myfunc` for 3 times, and it happens that my PC has 12 cores. But when I try to use `parfor` like:

```
parfor lp
myfunc()
end
```

Only the outmost parfor will be used.

I wonder is there any other way to separate cores in groups, for example each group has 4 cores, and there should be 3 groups in total, which allow me to use all 12 cores simultaneously.

All the cpus should be occupied. Because myfunc is a complicated function which means I can not change that easily, just consider that as a built-in function. I need to focus on the group.

Comment: First of all, how did you configure your parallel pool? Is it thread-based or process-based? I'm not sure about the process-based pool, but in the thread-based model, the worker threads have lots of limitations, only a subset of the language is supported. But it is possible that even in the process-based pool you cannot do this. MATLAB is complex, and having MATLAB workers spawn even more workers could be a dangerous thing.

Comment: my parallel parts are independent, which means both thread-based and process-based can be used. But I have no idea how to reach my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/nested-parfor-loops-and-for-loops.html) says that this is not possible:

> You cannot nest parfor directly within another parfor-loop. A parfor-loop can call a function that contains a parfor-loop, but you do not get any additional parallelism.

and

> You cannot nest parfor-loops because parallelization can be performed at only one level.

So, it is just not possible to do what you want to do without rewriting the function.